# Flutter chrome extension Pasteboard.image (clipboard image) returns null

Tags: flutter, google-chrome-extension, pasteboard

I created a webapp first and the following code works to copy image from clipboard:

```
final imageBytes = await Pasteboard.image;
```

Web app though gives a popup for permission before pasting the image but works.

I converted the app to flutter chrome extension. I don't get any popup for permission and the imageBytes is null.

I have already added following permissions in manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite"]
```

Comment: Is this a content script? These permissions apply only to pages of the extension and not to the web page where the content script runs.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I had to add the permission from extension settings in "View Web Permissions". Changed "Clipboard permission" from "Ask" to "Allow" as shown in the image.

[image]